# If $M$ is finitely generated then so is $M/IM$ for an ideal $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R$-module an $I\subset R$ an ideal. If $M$ is finitely generated, then would $M/IM$ be finitely generated? My guess would be yes, since if $M$ is finitely generated, we can choose generators $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ for $M$ and so $[m_1]_{IM},\ldots, [m_r]_{IM}$ would be generators for $M/IM$ right? I'm a little in doubt, since $I$ could be infinite.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but probably the question is to prove that $M/IM$ is finitely generated as a module over $R/I$.

Maybe it's better to split the proof into two parts.

1. If $M$ is finitely generated and $f\colon M\to N$ is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism, then also $N$ is finitely generated.
2. If $N$ is finitely generated as $R$-module and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $IN=0$, then $N$ is finitely generated also as $R/I$-module.

Both statements admit a simple proof.

For 1, consider $\{m_1,\dots,m_k\}$ a set of generators of $M$. Then $\{f(m_1),\dots,f(m_k)\}$ is a set of generators for $N$.

Statement 2 follows from the fact that, for $x\in N$, the action of $R/I$ is defined by $(r+I)x=rx$.

Now use $N=M/IM$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. – José Carlos Santos 44 mins ago